# Data factory copy activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to mention only start of the cell in `Range` while using excel as source in copy acivity?

[image]

It throws the error, asking me to provide with the end cell value. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try only to use A5 in range without colon.

Answer (score 0):

ADF Excel range auto detects the end range.
So you need to put only A5 and not A5:

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to mention only start of the cell in `Range` while using excel as source in copy acivity?

To use only start of the of the cell in `Range` while using excel  you need to just mention cell name without colon.

> As per [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel#dataset-properties)
>
> > - Not specified: reads the whole worksheet as a table from the first non-empty row and column
> > - `A3`: reads a table starting from the given cell, dynamically detects all the rows below and all the columns to the right
> > - `A3:H5`: reads this fixed range as a table
> > - `A3:A3`: reads this single cell

**You can see in below image:**

[image]